# Add filter after Devise authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I need to add `around_action :set_time_zone` (or `before_filter :set_time_zone`) to the application controller. The problem is that the `current_user` is always `nil` because the Devise authentication is run after the filter.

**I would like to run the filter after Devise authentication so that I can access the `current_user` and get the time zone.**

My code:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  around_action :set_time_zone

  private

  def set_time_zone
    current_user.time_zone # this raises an expception because current_user is nil
  end
end

class ExampleController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

I would like to keep `authenticate_user!` in the `ExampleController` and keep `set_time_zone` in the `ApplicationController`.

I have also tried using `append_before_filter :set_time_zone`but it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: I have opened an issue on Github: [append_before_action is run before before_action](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31259)

Answer (score 0):

Recall that Devise uses Warden behind the scenes and it supplies a number of callbacks for you.
Take a look at the [`after_authentication`](https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/callbacks#after_authentication) callback which executes every time the user is authenticated (first time in each session):

ex:

```
Warden::Manager.after_authentication do |user,auth,opts|
  user.time_zone
end
```

Just create a new initializer file and put the code there. (*/config/initializers/warden_callbacks.rb*)

Comment: This is a useful tip! However sometimes I use the API key for authentication so I can't rely on Devise completely, I need to rely on Rails filters in the controller.

Comment: Oh I see! let me search around see what I can find. Great question!